# Gradient of Robust SVDD

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

In the process of opimizing the obj function in Robust SVDD.
How to obtain the gradient of the objective function using the chain rule?
$$J(R, c) = R + C \sum_{i=1}^N max(0,||x_i - c||-R)$$

R is the radius of the boundary and c is the vector representing the center of the boundary. And x_i is the one of the data points.